# Formatting Number Field to Currency Using TO_CHAR returning hash characters

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, currency-formatting

I am running a simple sum and conversion to currency on a NUMBER field in an Oracle database.

My query is:

```
select 
TO_CHAR(eve.data_entry_date, 'yyyy-mm'), wtc.description as WORK_TYPE,
TO_CHAR(sum(sev.amount),'$999,999.99') AS "Total Invoice Amount"

from
EVENT eve,
SOW_EVENT sev,
WORK_TYPE_CODE wtc, 
SOW_WORK_TYPE_XREF swt,
WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE wti

where 
eve.event_number_id = sev.event_number_id
and sev.WORK_TYPE_CODE = WORK_TYPE_CODE
and sev.event_number_id = swt.event_number_id

group by 
TO_CHAR(eve.data_entry_date, 'yyyy-mm'), wtc.description
```

The query runs successfully, however the amounts showing up in the "Total Invoice Amount" column are returning hashes like:

```
Year-Month   WORK_TYPE         Total Invoice AMount
2019-01      Physical Work     ############
2019-01      Technical Work    ############
```

I had thought I just needed to resize the column, but that didn't work. When I just run:

```
sum(sev.amount)
```

it populates the amounts, just not formatted as currency as the 'amount' column is a number column. Any idea why I am getting the hashes when I format to currency?

Comment: What are the actual (unformatted) numbers - do they have more digits than the format mask you're using?

Comment: Funny, @AlexPoole. I was playing around with that and just discovered that (First time I tried to use this type of conversion). If you want to post that as an answer, I'll up vote and approve. For the record, the amount I was summing was in the tens of millions, so the mask I used above was too short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-24E16D8D-25E4-4BD3-A38D-CE1399F2897C):

> All number format models cause the number to be rounded to the specified number of significant digits. If a value has more significant digits to the left of the decimal place than are specified in the format, then pound signs (#) replace the value. This event typically occurs when you are using `TO_CHAR` with a restrictive number format string, causing a rounding operation.

Your format mask needs enough digit placeholders for the highest value you expect to see. At the moment the values seem to be above a million.